# can you specify a content file to be used as default in contentplaceholder?

Tags: asp.net

Can you specify a page, for example "listEvents.aspx" to be the default content source instead of default.aspx? If not, can I make it redirect from default.aspx to somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).
2. In **Features View**, double-click **Default Document**.
3. In the **Actions** pane, click **Add**.
4. In the **Name** box, type the file name that you want to add to the list of default documents and then click **OK**. This file name will be added to the top of the default document list.
5. Optionally, select a default document in the list and in the **Actions** pane, click **Move Up** or **Move Down** to change the file's precedence.
6. Optionally, select a default document in the list, and in the **Actions** pane, click **Remove** to remove any file names that you do not want to use as default documents.